# Why does Checkbox widget not appear on RecyclerView's CardView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-checkbox

I have a RecyclerView list populated by CardViews.  I tried to add a Checkbox to the left side of the CardView and nothing happens.  Only the two TextViews appear.  What am I missing here?

card_layout.xml:

```
...
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/singlecard_view1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_margin="4dp">

    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"  >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/chkSelected"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"  />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cardBlankText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/chkSelected"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/chkSelected"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textAlignment="center" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cardBlankText3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/cardBlankText2"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/cardBlankText2"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textAlignment="center"  />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
...
```

DataModel.java:

```
public class DataModel {

private String todo;
private String note1;
private boolean isSelected;

public String getTodo() {
    return todo;
}

public void setTodo(String todo) {
    this.todo = todo;
}

public String getNote1() {
    return note1;
}

public void setNote1(String note1) {
    this.note1 = note1;
}


public boolean isSelected() {
    return isSelected;
}

public void setSelected(boolean isSelected) {
    this.isSelected = isSelected;
}
}
```

Adapter.java:

```
...
public class ListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    CheckBox chkSelected;
    TextView cardBlankText2;
    TextView cardBlankText3;

    public ListViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        chkSelected = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.chkSelected);
        cardBlankText2 = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardBlankText2);
        cardBlankText3 = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardBlankText3);

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ListViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.chkSelected.setChecked(dbList.get(position).isSelected());
        holder.chkSelected.setTag(dbList.get(position));
        holder.cardBlankText2.setText(dbList.get(position).getTodo());
        holder.cardBlankText3.setText(dbList.get(position).getNote1());
     }
...
}
```

[image]

Comment: it not display checkbox?

Comment: correct, it does not display the checkbox.

Comment: it not display on design screen or runing ?

i try, it have check box. 
i copy code of you
design screen: http://i.imgur.com/bwxV9wW.png

and running: http://i.imgur.com/Ni09PYB.png

Comment: I am using Genymotion Emulator so it does not display when running the app.

Comment: but why i try with code of you, it have check box

Comment: Not sure why it is working for you and not for me.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the problem of third textview's match parent width

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/cardBlankText3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

It's a common bug that "match_parent" couldn't just fill up the rest of the space but occupied the whole view. (And, yes, in preview, it's totally no problem)

If you want to have the third textview fill up just the rest space after the checkbox and 2nd textview. You could try

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/cardBlankText3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

To avoid textview 2 is too long and leave no space for textview 3, you should also set a max width too. Something like this.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/cardBlankText2"
    android:maxWidth="160dp"
```

Just take a magic number you like.

If you want to have textview 2 and textview 3 divide the space evenly. You can make use of LinearLayout, weight_sum and weight.

Comment: @JT Ok, I will try.  Be back in a minute.

Comment: @JT no luck, the checkbox never shows.  And I tried match_parent and wrap_content for cardBlankText2.  I set the maxWidth=40dp.

Comment: What support library version are you using?

Comment: appcompat, cardview and recyclerview are v7:23.01

Comment: how about get a try on the latest one, 23.3.0?

Comment: Could you also screenshot on how the checkbox wasn't shown?

Comment: Ok, 1 minute and then I'll post it.

Comment: See screenshot above.  "850" is the first TextView cardBlankText2 and "985" is the second TextView cardBlankText3.   I will update to latest support library and see if there is any change.

Comment: No change with the updated support library to 23.3.0.

Comment: OK, from the screenshot looks like the item layout is quite different from you code provided. Could you try with parent view LinearLayout instead of Relative layout?